# how to get the second value from select option in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, split

How do I get the second value of "investortype" and show it within "exploremax"?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function $(id) {
        return document.getElementById(id);
    }

    function addCommas(nStr) // adds commas for long numbers in function explore().. eg. 123456 = 123,456
    {
        nStr += '';
        x = nStr.split('.');
        x1 = x[0];
        x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
        var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
        while (rgx.test(x1)) {
            x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
        }
        return x1 + x2;
    }

    function explore() { // this function will calculate how much credits_all and credits_2_all it costs to explore "total". In addition to that I’d also like it to show exploremax.. but it doesn’t work.

        var value = document.getElementById(investortype).value;
        var split = value.split(":");
        var v1 = split[0];
        var v2 = split[1];

        var toexplore = Number($("toexplore").value);
        var total = Number($("total").value);
        var exploremax = Math.round(((total * 0.12 * v2) * 1) / 1);
        var credit = Math.round(((total * 0.51 * v1) + 700) * Math.pow(10, 10)) / Math.pow(10, 10);
        var credit_2 = Math.round(((total * 0.51 * v1) + 850) * Math.pow(10, 10)) / Math.pow(10, 10);
        var credit_all = addCommas(Math.round((toexplore * credit) * 1) / 1);
        var credit_2_all = addCommas(Math.round((toexplore * credit_2_all) * 1) / 1);
        var show_exploremax = addCommas(exploremax);

        if ((toexplore == "" || toexplore == null) && (total == "" || total == null)) {
            $("credit_all").innerHTML = "Error";
            $("credit_2_all").innerHTML = "Error";
            $("show_exploremax").innerHTML = "Error";
        } else {
            $("credit_all").innerHTML = credit_all;
            $("credit_2_all").innerHTML = credit_2_all;
            $("show_exploremax").innerHTML = show_exploremax;
        }
    }
</script>
```

I added the HTML. "show_exploremax" is supposed to read the second value from the "investortype" dropdown menu, but I’m having trouble getting it to do that.

```
<form action="" id="explore_cost">
<p>
<table width="50%" cellspacing="0px" align="center">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="center"><b>Land Explore Cost</b></td>
  </tr>    
    <tr>
        <td>Investor type:</td>
        <td align="center"><select id="investortype" class="dropdown">
                <option value="1:1">Standard</option>
                <option value="1.2:0.5">Invasive</option>
                <option value="1.1:0.9">Economist</option>
                <option value="0.1:9.99">Self-sufficient</option>
                <option value="1:1">2nd credit</option>
                <option value="1.1:1">Researcher</option>
      <!-- I tried to split the values with ":" -->          
            </select>  
        </td>   
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td >Amount of Land:</td>
        <td align="center"><input id="total" type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Land to explore:</td>
        <td align="center"><input id="toexplore" type="text" /></td>
    </tr>                              
    <tr>
        <td>Credit Needed:</td>
        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;<font id="credit_all"></font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2nd credit Needed:</td>
        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;<font id="credit_2_all"></font></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>Explore max:</td>
        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;<font id="show_exploremax"></font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><br />
        <td align="center" colspan="2"><input type="button" value="Submit" class="button1" onclick="explore()" /></td>
    </tr>    
</tbody>
```

EDIT: added html.

Comment: Putting essential pieces of your question in off-site links is not a good thing.  There's no guarantee that that site/page won't disappear rendering your question worthless (which is one reason why you're getting so many down votes),  Please include the HTML in your question.

Comment: The main problem is that "show_exploremax" is a font tag.

Comment: is that a critical problem? It worked with "credit_all" and "credit_2_all". Then when I added "show_exploremax", nothing worked anymore.

Comment: there's a syntax errors...

    document.getElementById(investortype).value; 

investortype is a string, should be in quotes

    document.getElementById("investortype").value

Comment: @user3817597 I was being partially facetious.  `font` tags have been deprecated for a *long* time and are not supported in HTML 5, although they should still allow setting the innerHTML.  The main problem is really due to the errors that Tank Jr. points out - but you should replace the use of `font` tags with CSS.  They don't do what you think they do.

Comment: @user3817597 Actually, it looks like you're not using the `font` tags to supply any style info anyway - you could probably just replace them with `span` tags.

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", init, false );

function init()
{
  var select = document.getElementById('investortype');
  select.addEventListener( "change", function() {
    var option = select.options[select.selectedIndex];
    document.getElementById('show_exploremax').innerText  = option.dataset.max;
  }, false);
  select.selectedIndex = -1;
};
```

```html
<h4>Pick One</h4>
<select id="investortype" class="dropdown">
  <option data-credit="1" data-max="1">Standard</option>
  <option data-credit="1.2" data-max="0.5" >Invasive</option>
  <option data-credit="1.1" data-max="0.9"  >Economist</option>
  <option data-credit="0.1" data-max="9.99" value="0.1:9.99">Self-sufficient</option>
  <option data-credit="1" data-max="1">2nd credit</option>
  <option data-credit="1.1" data-max="1">Researcher</option>
</select>

<h4>2nd option:</h4>
Max: <span id="show_exploremax"></span>
```